# Struct Compile Time Error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have written a program that catches `<ctrl> + <c>` signals and then outputs a list, but I have one compile-time error that I can't seem to get past.  I keep receiving this error:

> cannot convert `void ()()' to `void (*)(int)' in assignment

According to the compiler the error is happening at this line of code:

```
    handler.sa_handler = handle_SIGINT;
```

Here is the surrounding code as well:

```
cmdcounter = 1;

/*set up the signal handler*/
struct sigaction handler;
handler.sa_handler = handle_SIGINT;
sigaction(SIGINT, &handler, NULL);

strcpy(buffer, "Caught <ctrl><c>\n");
```

`handle_SIGINT` is defined earlier in the program:

```
void handle_SIGINT()
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, strlen(buffer));

    // Print out last 10 commands that were used.
    printf("Most recent commands entered:\n");
    if(cmdcounter <= 10) {
        for (i=0; i < cmdcounter; i++) {
            printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, cmd[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i = cmdcounter-10; i < cmdcounter; i++) {
            printf("%d. %f\n", i, cmd[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine to me, but something is obviously not.  Does anyone know what is throwing this error?

Comment: Where is `handle_SIGINT` defined?

Comment: handle_SIGINT is defined earlier int the program as its own function

Comment: You should include that in your question.

Comment: Ok I added the handle_SIGINT function to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `handle_SIGINT` is wrong.

<strike>Show us that function, and we'll be able to tell you exactly how it is wrong.</strike>

`handle_SIGINT` is *SUPPOSED* to be:

```
void handle_SIGINT(int){....}
```

You left out the `int` part as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that the signatures do not match. `handle_SIGINT` should be:

```
void handle_SIGINT(int ){ ... }
```